# can't start a cider REPL after trying to update cider

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

After trying to update Cider, I've been unable to start a repl.

I get the following error message, apparently showing a problem with Leiningen:

```
Loading c:/emacs/graphviz-dot-mode.el (source)...
graphviz-dot-mode.el: (lambda (elm) ...) quoted with ' rather than with #' [4 times]
Loading c:/emacs/graphviz-dot-mode.el (source)...done
Loading c:/emacs/xml-rpc.el (source)...
xml-rpc.el: (lambda (p) ...) quoted with ' rather than with #'
Loading c:/emacs/xml-rpc.el (source)...done
Loading c:/emacs/py/emacs-for-python/epy-init.el (source)...
Loading c:/emacs/py/emacs-for-python/extensions/flymake-patch.el (source)...done
Loading c:/emacs/py/emacs-for-python/extensions/flymake-cursor.el (source)...done
py/emacs-for-python/extensions/auto-complete/auto-complete.el: `flet' is an obsolete macro (as of 24.3); use either `cl-flet' or `cl-letf'.
Loading c:/emacs/py/emacs-for-python/epy-init.el (source)...done
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
Making nrepl-create-client-buffer-function local to *nrepl-server graphics* while let-bound!
Making nrepl-use-this-as-repl-buffer local to *nrepl-server graphics* while let-bound!
Starting nREPL server via "c:/Users/Owner/.lein/bin/lein.bat" update-in :dependencies conj ^"[org.clojure/tools.nrepl \^"0.2.12\^"]^" -- update-in :plugins conj ^"[cider/cider-nrepl \^"0.13.0-SNAPSHOT\^"]^" -- repl :headless...
error in process sentinel: nrepl-server-sentinel: Could not start nREPL server: warning: extra args ignored after '"c:/Users/Owner/.lein/bin/lein.bat'
Leiningen is a tool for working with Clojure projects.
```

Can anyone tell me what the issue might be?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not vary familiar with running emacs and clojure on Windows, but that error seems to indicate there is an argument mismatch. The first thing I would try is see if you can run lein repl. That should tell you if lein is OK.

Are you using elpa to install clojure-mode and cider? If not, that would be the best way to ensure things are up-to-date. Note that if you are using elpa, then perhaps removing the cider package and installing it again might help. cider gets lots of updates and your problem may just be a transient issue which has already been fixed. I would also check the cider site to see if there are any known issues.

I updated over the weekend to the latest (then) cider and have been running it with no problems on OSX.

Comment: Yes, I'm using elpa and yes, lein repl works.  Thanks for the advice, I tried updating and it didn't help.

Comment: I would be tempted to just totally delete the cider elpa package directory and see if a full re-install works. On one machine, I have to do this every time I try an org-plus-contrib upgrade and on another, the upgrade always works (one Linux, one OSX). Try enabling debug-on-error and see what backtrace you get for both cider-jack-in and cider-connect. Might provide enough info for better advice.